# Swift Syntax Error and init()?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift-playground

I study swift. I have a question about initializers `init()`.
For example, I want to initialize Int.

```
var number: Int  = 20
var number = Int(20)
var number = Int.init(20)
```

All expression is same?
Second, Why this expression occurs?

```
var check = "123"
var phoneNum:Int?
if((phoneNum = Int.init(check)) != nil)
{
    print("Success");
}
```

There is no error!

```
var check = "123"
var phoneNum:Int? = Int.init(check)

if(phoneNum != nil)
{
    print("Success");
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect an error?

Comment: Swift is not C. In Swift, an assignment doesn't yield a value.

Comment: I think Swift like C. I study hard Swift! Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, these all have the same effect:

   ```
   var number: Int  = 20
   var number = Int(20)
   var number = Int.init(20)
   ```

   And this is one more way to do it:

   ```
   var number = 20
   ```
2. This produces an error:

   ```
   var check = "123"
   var phoneNum:Int?
   if((phoneNum = Int.init(check)) != nil)
   {
       print("Success");
   }
   ```

   You get an error (“error: value of type '()' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed”) because assignment in Swift returns `()`, the sole value of type Void, but `nil` is type Optional, which is different than Void. Assignments in Swift cannot generally be used as expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add this as a comment to [rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff)'s answer but since I don't have enough reputation, here's my answer as? a comment (pun intended ;).

Regarding the last two examples you can also use [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) to help in an assignment:

```
var check = "123"

var phoneNumber: Int?

if let number = Int.init(check) {
    phoneNumber = number
    print("Success")
}

print(phoneNumber)

// Success
// Optional(123)
```

Changing the `check` value:

```
var check = "A23"

var phoneNumber: Int?

if let number = Int.init(check) {
    phoneNumber = number
    print("Success")
}

print(phoneNumber)

// nil
```

I hope this helps too.